# Precision upto 2 decimal points in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

`print(round((8/4),2))` gives `2.0` and not `2.00`. What if I want precision upto 2 decimal points and don't want to use  `print("{0:.2f}".format(8/4))` in Python

Is it possible with `round()` ?

Comment: this is discussed in the docs https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Answer (score 1):

With `decimal` module and `quantize` method ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize)):

```
from decimal import Decimal

print((Decimal(8)/Decimal(4)).quantize(Decimal('1.00')))
```

Prints:

```
2.00
```

Answer (score 1):

> print(round((8/4),2)) gives 2.0 and not 2.00.

Actually it gives 2 because this can be represented exactly by the underlying base 2 (binary) arithmetic. It’s important to realize that any display is, in a real sense, an illusion: you’re simply rounding the display of the true machine value.

> What if I want precision up to 2 decimal points and don't want to use print("{0:.2f}".format(8/4)) in Python

That depends on what you mean. Do you want a decimal that could be anywhere from 1.995 to 2.005 etc. In that case your probably look for a structured data wrapper like the decimal module but if you only care about the display value than formatting is the way to go.

> Is it possible with round() ?

Well rounding the true value of 2 get you 2. You cannot get any closer to the exact value of 2 than 2.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `fstring` instead of format:

```
a = 8 / 2
precision = 2
print(f"{a: .{precision}f}")
```

output:

```
4.00
```